# SQL Varchar to milliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-update

I have a column in my MySql database which stores a date as a string "dd/mm/yyyy" is there a way for me to have this in an update query where I can check if the date in the table is overdue compared to now().

I've had a look at the CONVERT function but can't figure out how to use it for my case.

Comment: Don't store dates in strings. EVER.  Especially in that format.  You will have major performance problems as your table size increases and you have no ability to properly index the data.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE()` converts the str string into a date value based on the fmt format string. The `STR_TO_DATE()` function may return a DATE , TIME, or DATETIME value based on the input and format strings. If the input string is illegal, the `STR_TO_DATE()` function returns NULL.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21/5/2013','%d/%m/%Y');
```

With time :-

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2013 1130','%d/%m/%Y %h%i') ;
```

compare with `now()`

```
Where now()=STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2013 1130','%d/%m/%Y %h%i') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE STR_TO_DATE(col, '%d/%m/%Y') > NOW()
```